# Not known implementation of typedef in C

Tags: c, typedef

I am confused about this example:

```
typedef int32_t voltage_dc_estimate_t[1];
```

Everything is OK but that `[1]` at the end of the type definition confuse me. Could someone please help me to understand that situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's going on, you have to breakdown the code part by part

```
typedef int32_t voltage_dc_estimate_t[1];
```

typedef is declaring a new type called voltage_dc_estimate_t, which is an array of int32_t of size 1.

Note that while this logical sense, it is a very bad idea to do this, because you are better off just doing

```
typedef int32_t voltage_dc_estimate_t;
```

if you are only trying to save 1 element.

Comment: There are some valid reasons to have an array typedef (although, yes, they can be confusing if it is unexpected).

Answer (score 3):

`[1]` means an array of `1` element.

`voltage_dc_estimate_t` is a type of an array of `1` element of type `int32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

To understand a `typedef` declaration, first understand what the declaration would be without it:

```
int32_t voltage_dc_estimate_t[1];
```

That would declare an array of `uint32_t` of length `1`, named `voltage_dc_estimate_t`.

The effect of `typedef` is that the name `voltage_dc_estimate_t` will represent the type of that variable instead of being an actual variable.  So in your example it means an array of `int32_t` of length `1`.